# Sent multiple request to the same URL separated by threads using CURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

How I can use multi threads using CURL in my case, because the function curl_multi_init() work for different urls. In my case I have only one url that I need to sent a large requests. The code below works to me very fine but, need more than 5 minutes for 1000 requests and my data can be more than 50K.

```
<?php 

class API {

private $url="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

public function __construct(){

}
public function __destruct() {

}   

public function callAPI($list, $country){
    
  $lists=explode(",",$list);

  $data=array();
  
  foreach ($lists as $element) {  

   $data[]=$this->callSingle($element, $country);
  
  }

  return json_encode($data);

}

private function callSingle($id, $country){

$url=$this->url.'/'.$country.'/'.$id;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$response = curl_exec($curl);   

curl_close($curl); 


return $response;

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you need to send so many requests to the same URL in such a short time?

Comment: I need to check one by one a large data that comes from the same url, that's why

Comment: Is it literally the same URL, or are you changing the ID and/or country each time you make the request? It wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes  as you can see the I check a large of IDs that comes from a list, and as response I get the information that corresponds to the ID

Comment: Does the API not provide a way to download all countries in one request, something like that? It would be the most obvious way to make it more efficient. You need to be careful making too many requests too quickly anyway as most professional APIs will rate limit you and maybe even ban you if it looks like you might use too many of their server resources.

Comment: The API endpoint its also managed from my company,  so there is not any way to ban me. The variable of this request is the ID not  country. The country is only to separate the amount of requests. The parameter that changed request by request is ID

Comment: I see. In that case I suggest writing this software in a language such as C# which supports genuine asynchronous tasks (both async I/O and multithreading). PHP doesn't really support that properly.